# More efficient way of using lots of if else statements

Tags: swift, if-statement

I'm trying to do this in swift and I was wondering if there was a more efficient way:

```
if(doesSmoke){
    yearsTotal = yearsTotal - 7.5
}
if hoursSleepAvg < 7 {
    yearsTotal = yearsTotal - yearsTotal / 100.0
}
if hoursSleepAvg > 8 {
    yearsTotal = yearsTotal - yearsTotal / 100.0
```

There are a lot more if statements. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Your last two checks seems to result in the same thing and are exclusive if each other, so you could just get rid of those checks.

Comment: switch statement?  How many other inputs do you have, besides doesSmoke & hoursSleepAvg?

Comment: Sleeping 7.5 hours per night seems to be best.

Comment: `yearsTotal = yearsTotal - yearsTotal / 100.0` can be also written as `yearsTotal *= 0.99`.

Answer (score 0):

You can consolidate different types of if statements into methods.

For example

```
main() {
   yearsTotal += accountForSmoke()
   yearsTotal += accountForSleep(yearsTotal)
}

func accountForSmoke() -> Double {
   return doesSmoke ? -7.5 : 0
}

func accountForSleep(_ yearsTotal: Double ) -> Double {
  if hoursSleepAvg < 7 {
    return -yearsTotal / 100.0
  }
  if hoursSleepAvg > 8 {
    return -yearsTotal / 100.0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator to simplify this.

```
yearsTotal = yearsTotal - (doesSmoke ? 7.5 : 0)
yearsTotal = (hoursSleepAvg < 7 || hoursSleepAvg > 8) ? (yearsTotal - yearsTotal / 100.0) : yearsTotal
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the logic as much as possible:

```
if (doesSmoke){
   yearsTotal -= 7.5
}

if hoursSleepAvg < 7 || hoursSleepAvg > 8 {
   yearsTotal *= 0.99
}
```

However, the logic is very questionable. It seems obvious that `hoursSleepAvg` won't have the same effect when it's equal to `7.00` and when it's equal to `7.99`.